# C# Prinitng modified date range in console

Tags: c#, date, datetime, console-application, date-range

I need to accept input paramteters and print date range in console like in the example:

input: "01.01.2017 05.01.2017"

output: "01 - 05.01.2017"

So as you see dates must be separated with dots and printed with dash between them. What is more, if start and end date both has the same month and year, these are printed only once.

Does anyone can suggest good way to achieve this?

Comment: You should definitely add some more details, including code. Please check here on how to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I would split this into two parts: 1) Converting the input into DateTime values. 2) Formatting that pair of values appropriately. They are entirely separable, and I'd hope you can find the answer to at least the first part in other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just format date as you need and add aditional check for cases.

```
        DateTime date1 = new DateTime();
        DateTime date2 = new DateTime();

//while not valid input dates format...
        bool valid = false;
        while (!valid)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter start date:");
            string dateEntered1 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter end date:");
            string dateEntered2 = Console.ReadLine();

             bool isvalidDate1 = DateTime.TryParse(dateEntered1,out date1);
            bool isvalidDate2 = DateTime.TryParse(dateEntered2,out date2);
//check if date parsing was sucess
            if(isvalidDate1 && isvalidDate2)
            {
                valid = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dates entered is in incorrect format!");

            }
        }
        string period = "";
        if (date1.Month == date2.Month && date1.Year == date2.Year)
        {
            period = string.Format("{0} - {1}", date1.ToString("dd."), date2.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
        }
        else
        {
            period = string.Format("{0} - {1}", date1.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"), date2.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
        }
        Console.Write(period);
        Console.Read();
```

Comment: Thanks. But i don't want to use DateTime.Now. I have to read someone's string input. I don't really know how i should convert the string values to DateTime parameters.

Comment: updated to read from console entered values  (without any validation, is date is entered correclty)

Comment: added validation, so output will work, if valid string for date will be in both inputs

Comment: Amazing. This is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks a lot! There is only missing else statement in futher part of code.

Comment: missed it, sorry, but if can read code, than that is no problem :)